# Typescript constructor: new vs class vs typeof class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, types

In Typescript, what is the difference between types T1-T4:

```
class MyClass {
}

type T1 = MyClass;
type T2 = typeof MyClass;
type T3 = new () => MyClass;
type T4 = { new(): MyClass };
```

Intellisense shows me different options but I can't tell what they actually point to.

Is there a difference between `T2`, `T3`, and `T4` since the following works:

```
const t1: T1 = new MyClass();
const t2: T2 = MyClass;
const t3: T3 = MyClass;
const t4: T4 = MyClass;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof` is a way to refer to the type of a value.
Example:

```js
let s = 'Hello'
let n: typeof s;
```

`n` would be type string.
[Link to typescript docs about typeof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html)

Looking at the JavaScript output from the TypeScript and using `console.log` on the variables, `T2`, `T3` and `T4` end up containing the constructor function for `MyClass`, i.e.: `function MyClass() {}`.
The TypeScript you wrote boils down to references to the MyClass constructor function I believe.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I will do some digging into the generated code. Thank you!