# Use of typeof in keyof types typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a `class`, containing a `static` and a non-`static` parameter:

```
class Test {
  s1 = "Hello"
  static s2 = 16
}
```

I then create 2 keyof types, one using typeof and one without:

```
type t1 = typeof Test[keyof typeof Test]
type t2 =  Test[keyof Test]
```

Type `t1` is a `union` between `Test | number` while type `t2` is `string`.

What is the actual difference between the two? Does typeof return the types of static methods + the class? Why? What is the reasoning?

Comment: This will clear it up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67992062/typescript-constructor-new-vs-class-vs-typeof-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr

- `typeof Test` as a type refers to the type of the value of `Test` (a class function).
- `Test` as a type refers to the type of an instance of `Test` (an object that looks like this: `{ s1: 'hello' }`).

#### `typeof`

`typeof` can do one of two things in TypeScript, depending on the context. From the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html):

> JavaScript already has a `typeof` operator you can use in an *expression* context:
>
> ```ts
> // Prints "string"
> console.log(typeof "Hello world");
> ```
>
> TypeScript adds a `typeof` operator you can use in a *type* context to refer to the *type* of a variable or property:
>
> ```ts
> let s = "hello";
> let n: typeof s; 
> //  ^ let n: string
> ```

The situation you have described is using the second `typeof` operator (existing in the *type* context).

#### Classes

TypeScript classes are a bit strange; every other declaration in TypeScript will result in a new type or a new object (almost, TypeScript enums are an exception). For example, you can't use a variable a type, nor a type as a variable:

```ts
const foo = 'bar';
const baz: foo = foo;
//         ^^^ 'foo' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. 
//             Did you mean 'typeof foo'?

interface fizz {
  buzz: string
}
const fizzbuzz = fizz['buzz'];
//               ^^^^ 'fizz' only refers to a type, 
//                    but is being used as a value here.
```

Declaring a class is different because you end up with **both a TypeScript type and a JavaScript class**, where the type represents an instance of the class. In other words, you can do this:

```ts
class Foo {}

// As a JavaScript constructor:
const foo = new Foo(); 

// As a TypeScript type:
let bar: Foo;

// As both:
const baz: Foo = new Foo();
```

One more thing to note: in JavaScript, [classes are just functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes#using_a_constructor), and functions are just objects. Adding a `static` property to a TypeScript class compiles to look something like this in JavaScript:

```js
// TypeScript 
//   class Foo { static bar = 'baz' }
// compiles to:
class Foo {
}
Foo.bar = 'baz';
```

#### `typeof Class`

Regardless of whether you use `typeof` in the expression context or the type context, you must always use it on a value type. In other words, you can't do:

```ts
type Abc = 'hi';
type Zyx = typeof Abc;
//                ^^^ 
// 'Abc' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Because of this, when we know that `typeof Test` is going to use the *value* of `Test` rather than its *type*; as you noted, this is different from the type, `Test`. So, what is the type of `typeof Test`?

Remember, JavaScript classes are just functions that can be used as constructors (try running `console.log(typeof Test)` for proof). `typeof Class` is going to give you a type that represents that constructor function with additional narrowing specific to that class. You could use it like so:

```ts
class Test {
  s1 = "Hello"
  static s2 = 16
}

type T = typeof Test;
const Foo: T = class Bar extends Test { }

// Because of duck typing, you can also do this:
class Test2 { 
  s1 = "Hello"
  static s2 = 32
}

const Fizz: T = class Buzz extends Test2 { }
```

In other words, `Test` as a type gives you the structure of an **instance**, while `typeof Test` as a type gives you the structure of **the class itself**.

Looking at the `keyof` behavior:

```
// The keys of an instance of test:
type Keys = keyof Test; // 's1'

// The keys of the Test class, which is just a function and so includes
// the inherited 'prototype' property:
type Keys2 = keyof typeof Test; // 'prototype' | 's2'
```

And finally:

```ts
type t1 = typeof Test[keyof typeof Test];
// -> typeof Test['prototype' | 's2'] -> Test | number
type t2 = Test[keyof Test]
// -> Test['s1'] -> string
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoa0IEZoF5oAiACXhBAHsjNskwkBLYbAJgOhwDZ0BfddEgCeAB3hwOwsZQBmcREgDc6YJQB2yaADFKlVgC4JhUJBgAhMACdo8AB5J4agCYwEm1NH4rwUecnYetLgcpORUNFjIDMxsHADMrHwCqhooWowAXhmGsBwmvmYArlk29o4ufkgBngJO8CaW4imaSDkKyoKi4gDW8EIwhL1CspXKUj19EOyDfSPjI25KnWLQSAAMkl0L7cviVRyLANpD28gAurureITzckcncreVFwIq6poyuhwA5EKI38oAPSA6DNFAAIyshk%20lA4MI6jDUDksMjAwHEMkyGTQtHBxWydEsiIA5klgaD3ihMVk8SVCNSModvrSMt8zh1vKZtF8PPwwdBIQSdLDCGp4AB3bmUAAUAEoOtKZIU1MAmOpoHKcVh8jBhWg6NEWCIfgALMKUb41WjkgCCMDA0AAUmAAG5gADKwCJIhQYMshVVlEs%20lo-JhHDFkuFco6WFt9rgXU93pQ4xDWBA8AhUKlseg8YFlCQJvTFNSArAQq%20oolUpjfFlcoE42gNvBLEI3xNjABlwAWkJbJtpHI28BFEA)